# Get latest record for each value in a collection field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my collection i have multiple records with same value for "name" field.
I want to retrieve a single record for each name with latest creation date.

Sample aggregation code which i tried.

```
db.m_collection.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: { name: "$name" } } }
] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) them by creationDate and then use [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/index.html) to get most recent date:

```
db.m_collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { "creationDate": 1 } },
    { $group: { _id: { name: "$name" }, lastDate: { $last: "$creationDate" } } }
] )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.m_collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      'date': -1 // retrieve data in descending order 
    }
  }
]).limit(10) // number of record you want to find.
```

Comment: There's no createdDate field available after you run $group